# git cvsimport missing tags

Tags: git, cvs2git, cvsimport

I'm migrating huge CVS repository into git and I've figured out that not all tags were migrated (*the history looks ok*). Probably it's because the Tags in CVS were created not on the whole repository, but on particular folders, and in addition some files in CVS history are dead.

`git cvsimport -p -x -v -a -i -d :pserver:ysn@uaap01:/mitarepo -C F:/GitImport    Libs/WP/Include/drivers` 
`cvs_direct initialized to CVSROOT /mitarepo
cvs rlog: Logging Mitalib/WP4000/Include/drivers
* UNKNOWN LINE * Branches:
Branch WP100_1_2_0_CANopen erroneously stems from itself -- changed ancestor to origin
Branch origin does not exist!
* UNKNOWN LINE * Branches:
Skipping WP100_1_2_0_CANopen
* UNKNOWN LINE * Branches:
* UNKNOWN LINE * Branches:`

I tried to import only specific folder from CVS, but the Tags are still missing

From all CVS Tags only API_4_51 and RE_OS_API_3_9 were imported, the rest was not. Is there a way to diagnose and fix this issue? By the way I can checkout any necessary files from CVS by Tags without a problem and commit 1.3 was migrated to Git normally.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with a huge repo with all manner of tags using `cvs2git` https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn

(`cvs2git` is part of `cvs2svn`. If you see links to cvs2git.tigris.org the above GitHub link is the same project in its new home.)